# Turning a for loop into a list comprehension

Tags: python

I have a `for` loop:

```
def decode(encoded):
    r = []
    a_l = string.ascii_letters
    r_l = a_l[::-1]
    for c in list(encoded):
        if c in r_l:
            i = a_l.index(c)
            c = r_l[i]
        r.append(c)
    return "".join(r)
```

I want to compress the entire function to one-liner.  So far, I've come up with:

```
r = [r_l[a_l.index(c)] for c in encoded if c in r_l]
```

This, however, skips over the punctuation characters.  How can I do this?

If you need a test string, it's an atbash cipher:

```
def atbash(payload):
    all_letters = string.ascii_letters
    all_letters_reversed = all_letters[::-1]
    retval = []
    for c in list(payload):
        if c in all_letters:
            index = all_letters.index(c)
            c = all_letters_reversed[index]
        retval.append(c)
    return ''.join(retval)
```

Comment: "I need to create that entire function on one line" almost certainly there is no _need_ to do this.

Comment: @roganjosh I _want_ to create a oneliner for this function, better?

Comment: If you want the result to be as long as the input you want `[a if b else c for d in e]`, not `[a for b in c if d]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the ternary part of the operation to add any "other" characters:

```
... if c in r_l ... else c ...
```

Now, you'll need to insert that `else c` into just the right place to be the alternative to your translated character.  I leave that as an exercise for the student.  I trust that hint unblocks your brain paths.

Answer (score 0):

As @Prune pointed out, you are missing the ternary portion of your list comprehension. Here is a much shorter implementation of your code using list comprehensions:

```
import string

def atbash(payload):

    return ''.join([r_l[a_l.index(c)] for c in list(payload) if c in a_l])

def decode(encoded):

    return ''.join([r_l[a_l.index(c)] if c in r_l else c for c in list(encoded)])

test = 'test'
a_l = string.ascii_letters
r_l = a_l[::-1]

x = atbash(test)

decode(x)
```